# Java spring caching, saveAll proper handling of update

Tags: java, spring, jpa, caching, spring-data

So I currently try to cache as much as possible **SAFELY** in my spring boot application.

Bud i run into brain scratcher.
**How do i handle saveAll(list of entities) method ?**

```
 public List<WorkaroundEntity> saveAll(List<WorkaroundEntity> workaroundEntities) {
```

This method saves all entities, My current cache looks like this :

```
  /**
    * K=WorkaroundEntity.id   --   Value=WorkaroundEntity
   */
   private static final String CACHE_NAME_WORKAROUNDS = "workarounds";
```

So basically my map has IDs AND entities.
When user saves LIST OF ALL ENTITIES. From my point of view I only have this option :

```
@CacheEvict(value = CACHE_NAME_WORKAROUNDS, allEntries = true, condition = "#workaroundEntities.size()>=1")
public List<WorkaroundEntity> saveAll(List<WorkaroundEntity> workaroundEntities) {
    return workaroundEntityRepository.saveAll(workaroundEntities);
}
```

**Am I wrong and is there a better solution for this kind of problem?**

So far i use this cache in methods :

```
public WorkaroundEntity save(WorkaroundEntity workaroundEntity)
public WorkaroundEntity findById(long id)
public void delete(WorkaroundEntity workaroundEntity) 
public WorkaroundEntity getOne(long id)
```

**How do you handle methods that work with collections instead of single entities?**

Comment: Don't use Spring Cache for this... Your JPA provider provides cache integration which you should use, which already takes care of all this. Don't use Spring Cache to cachage repository method calls. Assuming that you are using Hibernate you should be looking in using 2nd level caching. Your save(all) method won't be called all the times when an entity gets updated/saved (managed entities have change detection and changes are persisted automatically) and your cache will not be up-to-date anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum bud by that notion i should not even use cache anotations for findById etc, :-O is that correct ? I will look into 2nd level caching

Comment: Correct you shouldn't... If you use 2nd level caching all entities can be cached and hibernate will update it accordingly, and also use it for fetching the data. In your case each method has its own cache and it will only store the results based on the incoming params and as a value the result. So it might even be that a query could store multiple instances of the same objeect (a findById and a findByName resulting in the same object could store the same one, if not using the proper keys etc.). IMHO Using Spring Cache to cache JPA entities is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @M.Deinum So from what i seen all i have to do is add @ Cacheable onto entities and framework will take care of it? Ofcourse configuring some stuff in application.properties etc, bud that just sounds too easy to be true  ;)

Comment: You need to identify which entities you would like to cache (hence the  `@Cacheable`) and configure hibernate to use 2nd level caching and actually configure the 2nd level cache. When configured correctly you could expose some Hibernate metrics to see if the cache gets hit or not. Beauty is that it will also take care of updates in the cache when updating/inserting entities. See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/

Comment: @M.Deinum I will do more research into this and try to implement it in my code. Thanks for the pointers  you helped me a lot. If you wanna combine this discussions into answer to get rep, please do so and i will accept it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the end , answer for me was to use hibernate 2nd level cache and spring cache together.** I got best of both words. In addition to this i have created additiona linternal caches to hit database even less.