# What are main benefits/differences [ spring-cache vs plain map caching ]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

So I recently added some spring-cache usage into my services bud the more i look at the the more i feel it just limits what i can do.

My initial impressions is that its less code heavy, i dont have to write as much code. Thats a plus.

Negative is that I dont have control over what gets cached as much, Usage of Ids, vs collections of entities passed to methods like saveAll etc, Also some methods that execute more complicated queries.

Is there something underneeth that im missing when it comes to spring cache? Some magic in the background or is this really just as simple as creating some concurrent hashmaps and putting data to them from services and taking data out or updating based on service method invocations?

Im 50 / 50 on using my own caching implementation vs spring-cachce. What are risks that i can run into that spring-cache already solves for me?

This question is under assumption that default cache manager is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses a default ConcurrentHashMap by default but if you include Caffeine (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) or Hazelcast in the classpath you get a different cache provider. The beauty of this is that you can configure the cache outside or your application without any code.

Comment: Yes im aware of how easy is to change provider, bud what puzzles me , what overhead it brings and what other possitives it gives me over using my own implementation which is way easier to control. Annotations liek cacheable either cache whole list  if list is used as parameter or  nothing. That sucks. I get that the bennefit of external configuration sounds good. Bud same can be done by def properties in application.properties

Comment: If a framework helps me to safe work and reduce code I would rely on the framework. For me that's the fundamental idea of Spring Boot, to make developer life easy. You can easily control whats coming into the cache with the annotation attributes https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html like `condition`.

Comment: Yhe i unserstand,  bud regarding the loss of control i was meaning more something like following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139460/java-spring-caching-saveall-proper-handling-of-update . Im looking into caffine cache now, I will try it and extend functionality to other services. If all works fine i guess, i can live with less control.

Comment: Acutally this video addresses a lot of questions that I had https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3McRajvmdlw Support for weak keys , preAllocated  capacity , refreshing, stat recording,  expiration etc. Seems there is more to cache implementations provided by vendors that i was aware of.